# How to draw a flow chart like this?

Tags: flow-charts

[image]

I want to have those remarks inside the rectangular box. Thank you so much.
So far I made this, but I don't know how to type more words inside the boxes. And how can I make those "Input" cloud and "Output" cloud at the position that I want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw,  
    text width=15em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=16em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse, node distance=6cm,
    minimum height=8em]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 10cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (init) {\underline{Machine}};
    \node [cloud, left of=init] (data) {\underline{Training data set}};
    \node [cloud, above right of=init] (input) {\underline{Input}};
    \node [cloud, below right of=init] (output) {\underline{Output}};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (data) -- (init);
    \path [line] (input) -- (init);
    \path [line] (init) -- (output);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? TikZ? Pstricks? Metapost? Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable example (MWE).

Comment: So far I made this, but I don't know how to type more words inside the boxes. And how can I make those "Input" cloud and "Output" cloud at the position that I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                positioning,    % <--- added
                shapes}
\usepackage{xparse}% So that we can have two optional parameters
\NewDocumentCommand\DownArrow{O{2.0ex} O{black}}%
{%
\mathrel{\tikz[baseline] \draw [<-, line width=0.5pt, #2] (0,0) -- ++(0,#1);}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm and 9mm,
 block/.style = {rectangle, draw, rounded corners,
                 text width =15em, align=center},
 cloud/.style = {draw, ellipse, aspect=1.2, align=center}
                    ]
% Place nodes
\node [block] (init) {\underline{Machine}\\
                      $f(\vec{x}) = \theta_0 + \theta_1x_1 + \dotsm + \theta_n x_n$\\[1ex]
                      $\DownArrow[30pt]$\\[1ex]
                      $y=\phi\bigl(f(\vec{x})\bigr)$
                      };
\node [cloud, left=of init] (data)
                    {\underline{Training data set}\\
                     dog, cat, pig, etc};
\node [cloud, above right=of init.east] (input)
                    {\underline{Input}\\
                     features data $\vec{x}$};
\node [cloud, below right=of init.east] (output)
                    {\underline{Output}\\
                     class: $y$};
% Draw edges
\draw[-latex']  (data) -- (init);
\draw[-latex']  (input) -- (init.east |- input);
\draw[-latex']  (init.east |- output) -- (output);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You were on the right track :). To your code I made the following changes:

- Correct the input encoding (it should be only one, recent `article` for default use `utf8`).
- For positioning, use the library `positioning` and its syntax (note `above right=of ...` instead your `above of = ...`).
- The use of `\tikzstyle` is not recomended. Instead of it, use `\tikzset` or define styles as options to `tikzpicture` (as I do in the above MWE).
- After defining `align=center`, you can write multi line (centered) text in the nodes

[image]

**edit:**
next iteration (should be closer to your sketch):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                positioning,    % <--- added
                shapes}
\usepackage{xparse}% So that we can have two optional parameters
\NewDocumentCommand\DownArrow{O{2.0ex} O{black}}%
{%
\mathrel{\tikz[baseline] \draw [<-, line width=0.5pt, #2] (0,0) -- ++(0,#1);}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm and 9mm,
 block/.style = {rectangle, draw, rounded corners,
                 text width =15em, align=center},
 cloud/.style = {draw, ellipse, aspect=1.2, align=center},
                    ]
% Place nodes
\node [block, label={[anchor=east, align=center, xshift=-1em,
                      font=\small\linespread{0.8}\selectfont, 
                      text=purple]right:
                $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$:\\
                 features\\ 
                 variables} 
       ] (init) {\underline{Machine}\\
                 $f(\vec{x}) = \theta_0 + \theta_1 x_1 + \dotsm + \theta_n x_n$\\[1ex]
                 $\DownArrow[30pt]$\\[1ex]
                 $y=\phi\bigl(f(\vec{x})\bigr)$
                 };
\node [cloud, left=of init] (data)
                 {\underline{Training data set}\\
                  dog, cat, pig, etc};
\node [cloud, above right=of init.east] (input)
                 {\underline{Input}\\
                  features data $\vec{x}$};
\node [cloud, below right=of init.east] (output)
                  {\underline{Output}\\
                   class: $y$};
% Draw edges
\draw[-latex']  (data) -- (init);
\draw[red,-latex']  (input) -- (init.east |- input);
\draw[red,-latex']  (init.east |- output) -- (output);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
In the last three years, packages `tikz` and document class `article` have undergone several additions, with which the above solution proposal can/had to be now  written as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,    % changed
                positioning,    % <--- added
                shapes}
\NewDocumentCommand\DownArrow{O{2.0ex} O{black}}%
{%
\mathrel{\tikz[baseline] \draw [Straight Barb-, semithick, #2] (0,0) -- ++(0,#1);}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm and 9mm,
 block/.style = {rectangle, draw, rounded corners,
                 text width =15em, align=center},
 cloud/.style = {draw, ellipse, aspect=1.2, align=center},
                    ]
% Place nodes
\node [block, label={[anchor=east, align=center, xshift=-1em,
                      font=\small\linespread{0.8}\selectfont,
                      text=purple]right:
                $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$:\\
                 features\\
                 variables}
       ] (init) {\underline{Machine}\\
                 $f(\vec{x}) = \theta_0 + \theta_1 x_1 + \dotsm + \theta_n x_n$\\[1ex]
                 $\DownArrow[30pt]$\\[1ex]
                 $y=\phi\bigl(f(\vec{x})\bigr)$
                 };
\node [cloud, left=of init] (data)
                 {\underline{Training data set}\\
                  dog, cat, pig, etc};
\node [cloud, above right=of init.east] (input)
                 {\underline{Input}\\
                  features data $\vec{x}$};
\node [cloud, below right=of init.east] (output)
                  {\underline{Output}\\
                   class: $y$};
% Draw edges
\draw[-Latex]  (data) -- (init);
\draw[red,-Latex]  (input) -- (init.east |- input);
\draw[red,-Latex]  (init.east |- output) -- (output);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result is almost the same as befone:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your great help. I have two more questions: 1. How to rescale the whole chart? 2. How to change the color of the arrow? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Alsacelei, (i) rescaling image is possible, but it is not good idea. is image to small or to big? (ii) color of arrows you can change on the way as is done in the second example: `\draw[red,-latex']  ...` where instead red color you use color which you like.

Comment: Thanks. It is too big. Because I am going to put it into the presentation slide, so I want to rescale the whole chart.

Comment: the best is ask new question that other people can see your problem . since my answer provide images as you ask in question, it will be nice from you that you accept it.

Comment: The `arrows` library is now official depreciated. One should use `arrows.meta`.

Comment: @James, thank you very much for the info. I added new version for possible solution, which consider your information and advances of `article` document class.